# Show a satellite image - leaflet map (javascript/jquery/css)

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, openstreetmap

All I want to show the two satellite map images like this: 
[image]

I have the image bounds, 4 parameters that define a tile (square):

```
21.00997925,42.72179487,21.00860596,42.72078596
22.00997925,43.72179487,22.00860596,43.72078596
```

or I can use the center of the square for example :

```
21.00997925,42.72179487
```

Here map is initialized:

```
<div class="row">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.3.1/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://matchingnotes.com/javascripts/leaflet-google.js"></script>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>MAP</h1>
        <div style="width:500px; height:500px" id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(51.51, -0.11), zoom: 9});
    var googleLayer = new L.Google('SATELLITE');
    map.addLayer(googleLayer);

})();
</script>
```

based on this [link](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay) I can do this:

```
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

Here I created a [JS Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/w5m6kcts/#&togetherjs=Ajkp4rNAhu)

Please, can somebody help me, how to display two satellite images based on latitude and longitude?

Comment: Sounds from your comments (below geocodezip's answer) that you do not need map navigation? In that case, you do need Leaflet at all. However, your screenshot shows extracts from Google Maps. IIRC, their Terms of Use prohibit the use of extracts, but you can go through them to make sure. In that case, you would indeed have to go through Google Maps API (or through Leaflet with a proxy plugin that uses those API), which is quite overkill as you figured out.

Comment: Would the static API be an option? You get an Img and can define to get it as satellite. But I don´t know how to handle bounds (or if this is even possible with static API). And I have currently no time, to verify that. Here is an example static API URL with satellite. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.712216,-74.22655&zoom=18&scale=false&size=600x300&maptype=satellite&format=png&visual_refresh=true

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display two maps, you need to create two separate maps.

```js
var map = new L.Map('map', {
  center: new L.LatLng(51.51, -0.11),
  zoom: 9
});
var googleLayer = new L.Google('SATELLITE');
map.addLayer(googleLayer);

var map2 = new L.Map('map2', {
  center: new L.LatLng(51.51, -0.11),
  zoom: 15
});
var googleLayer = new L.Google('SATELLITE');
map2.addLayer(googleLayer);
```

```css
html {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%
}
body {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
#map,
#map2 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://matchingnotes.com/javascripts/leaflet-google.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm trying to implement for 2 images but actually, I have to display 12 tiles or images so if I do like this I need to create too many maps.  The thing is that I don't need to zoom  those images, those just need to be loaded  in a specific width and height and that's all nothing else ?  The thing is that I'm confused and I can't define if I need to render the map or if I can show the images separately?

Comment: you just need a satellite image? No map actions?